# mysql datetime indexed column - varied query response time

Tags: mysql, datetime, select, indexing, datetime-format

EVENT_TIME is an indexed datetime column (Table Definition below). And almost all of my queries is based on EVENT_TIME column. I need a wide variety of options (like between, group by, DATE(EVENT_TIME),HOUR(EVENT_TIME) etc) to base my queries.

Not sure why there is huge difference between = and (like and DATE(EVENT_TIME)) conditions as mentioned below.

Any suggestions to query the most fastest way of say  **per day**-DATE(EVENT_TIME=today()), **last 4 hours** etc

```
select * from 4gc_1h_atch_enb where EVENT_TIME='2014-04-08 00:00:00'
```

60743 row(s) returned
**0.062 sec / 3.229 sec**

```
select * from 4gc_1h_atch_enb where EVENT_TIME like '2014-04-08 00:00:0%'
```

60743 row(s) returned
**449.875 sec / 7.988 sec**

```
select * from 4gc_1h_atch_enb where date(EVENT_TIME)='2014-04-08' and time(event_time)='00:00:00'
```

60743 row(s) returned
**401.094 sec / 9.063 sec**

**Table Definiton**

```
mysql> show create table 4gc_1h_atch_enb \G
*************************** 1. row **********************
       Table: 4gc_1h_atch_enb
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `4gc_1h_atch_enb` (
  `ELEMENT_TYPE` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `NE_VERSION` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `NE_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `NE_NAME` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `EVENT_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENB` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  .
  .
  .
TRUNCATED FOR READABILITY
  .
  .
  .
  `MarketName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  KEY `iNE_VERSION` (`NE_VERSION`),
  KEY `iNE_ID` (`NE_ID`),
  KEY `iNE_NAME` (`NE_NAME`),
  KEY `iEVENT_TIME` (`EVENT_TIME`),
  KEY `iENB` (`ENB`),
  KEY `iMarketName` (`MarketName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `=` or `BETWEEN` MySQL can use the index, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html . If you use `LIKE` or `DATE` then the result will be a computed field and MySQL will not use an index.

Check the execution plan of your different queries with `EXPLAIN`, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html